# why this analytical formula can't yields the answer of numerical integration?

Tags: numerical-integration

I have an initial function as follows

```
intrp[r_, re_] := (
 E^(-2 r (\[Alpha] + 
     r \[Beta])) (-E^(-((
      2 (me re^2 + mp (r + re) (r + re + 2 me re)) \[Gamma])/M^2)) + 
    E^(-((2 \[Gamma] (me (-mp r^2 + re^2 + mp re^2) + (1 + 
           me) mp RealAbs[r - re]^2))/M^2))) M^2)/(
 4 (1 + me) mp \[Gamma]);
```

where the constants are

```
me = 1;
mp = 1;
M = mp + me;
\[Omega] = 0.0001;
{\[Alpha], \[Beta]}={0.50000000206214434417262282295268960297107696533203, 
 1.1754907046612932983601436560949782261786822346039*10^-8};
\[Gamma] = SetPrecision[0.5*M*\[Omega], 50];
norm=0.00014216419373200363465950006063;
```

I go to the next step using both `Integrate` and `NIntegrate` and I expect to get the same result, but I don't!
For the next step I have

```
int[re_] :=(2*\[Pi])/re norm^2*Integrate[r intrp[r, re], {r, 0, \[Infinity]}];
nint[re_] := (2*\[Pi])/re norm^2*
   NIntegrate[r intrp[r, re], {r, 0, \[Infinity]}];
```

Now if you evaluate the `Integrate` command in `int[re]` and then call its result as int2[re] which has the following form

```
int2[re_] := (E^(-((2 (me + mp + 2 me mp) re^2 \[Gamma])/M^2))
     M^2 norm^2 \[Pi]^(
    3/2) (-E^(((2 \[Alpha] - (4 (1 + me) mp re \[Gamma])/M^2)^2/(
        8 (\[Beta] + (mp \[Gamma])/M^2)))) M^2 \[Alpha] + 
      E^((2 \[Alpha] + (4 (1 + me) mp re \[Gamma])/M^2)^2/(
       8 (\[Beta] + (mp \[Gamma])/M^2))) M^2 \[Alpha] + 
      2 E^((2 \[Alpha] - (4 (1 + me) mp re \[Gamma])/M^2)^2/(
       8 (\[Beta] + (mp \[Gamma])/M^2))) mp re \[Gamma] + 
      2 E^((2 \[Alpha] + (4 (1 + me) mp re \[Gamma])/M^2)^2/(
       8 (\[Beta] + (mp \[Gamma])/M^2))) mp re \[Gamma] + 
      2 E^((2 \[Alpha] - (4 (1 + me) mp re \[Gamma])/M^2)^2/(
       8 (\[Beta] + (mp \[Gamma])/M^2))) me mp re \[Gamma] + 
      2 E^((2 \[Alpha] + (4 (1 + me) mp re \[Gamma])/M^2)^2/(
       8 (\[Beta] + (mp \[Gamma])/M^2))) me mp re \[Gamma] + 
      E^((2 \[Alpha] - (4 (1 + me) mp re \[Gamma])/M^2)^2/(
       8 (\[Beta] + (mp \[Gamma])/M^2)))
        M^2 \[Alpha] Erf[(M^2 \[Alpha] - 2 (1 + me) mp re \[Gamma])/(
        Sqrt[2] M^2 Sqrt[\[Beta] + (mp \[Gamma])/M^2])] - 
      2 E^((2 \[Alpha] - (4 (1 + me) mp re \[Gamma])/M^2)^2/(
       8 (\[Beta] + (mp \[Gamma])/M^2)))
        mp re \[Gamma] Erf[(
        M^2 \[Alpha] - 2 (1 + me) mp re \[Gamma])/(
        Sqrt[2] M^2 Sqrt[\[Beta] + (mp \[Gamma])/M^2])] - 
      2 E^((2 \[Alpha] - (4 (1 + me) mp re \[Gamma])/M^2)^2/(
       8 (\[Beta] + (mp \[Gamma])/M^2)))
        me mp re \[Gamma] Erf[(
        M^2 \[Alpha] - 2 (1 + me) mp re \[Gamma])/(
        Sqrt[2] M^2 Sqrt[\[Beta] + (mp \[Gamma])/M^2])] - 
      E^((2 \[Alpha] + (4 (1 + me) mp re \[Gamma])/M^2)^2/(
       8 (\[Beta] + (mp \[Gamma])/M^2)))
        M^2 \[Alpha] Erf[(M^2 \[Alpha] + 2 (1 + me) mp re \[Gamma])/(
        Sqrt[2] M^2 Sqrt[\[Beta] + (mp \[Gamma])/M^2])] - 
      2 E^((2 \[Alpha] + (4 (1 + me) mp re \[Gamma])/M^2)^2/(
       8 (\[Beta] + (mp \[Gamma])/M^2)))
        mp re \[Gamma] Erf[(
        M^2 \[Alpha] + 2 (1 + me) mp re \[Gamma])/(
        Sqrt[2] M^2 Sqrt[\[Beta] + (mp \[Gamma])/M^2])] - 
      2 E^((2 \[Alpha] + (4 (1 + me) mp re \[Gamma])/M^2)^2/(
       8 (\[Beta] + (mp \[Gamma])/M^2)))
        me mp re \[Gamma] Erf[(
        M^2 \[Alpha] + 2 (1 + me) mp re \[Gamma])/(
        Sqrt[2] M^2 Sqrt[\[Beta] + (mp \[Gamma])/M^2])]))/(8 Sqrt[
    2] (1 + me) mp re \[Gamma] (M^2 \[Beta] + 
      mp \[Gamma]) Sqrt[\[Beta] + (mp \[Gamma])/M^2]);
```

when I tried `nint[10]` ,`int[10]`and `int2[10]` for example I get two different results.nemely:

```
int[10]
int2[10]
nint[10]
(* 4.975964881910113112577562173393203988238793355023312`27.\
85176023066818*^-7
0``-2135.7355398006894
4.975964881910046`*^-7 *)
```

I know the answer of `NIntegrate` is the real answer. It seems so odd why the analytic form can't yield the right answer?

I would be very grateful if somebody can help me, because I need to use the analytic form.

Comment: "you get different answers!": for what further calculations? Can you show the exact code in which you used the results of Integrate?

Comment: I updated the question, please read it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)
```

Use exact numbers whenever possible and the precision of `norm` should be consistent with the other values.

```
me = 1;
mp = 1;
M = mp + me;
ω = 10^-4;
{α, β} = {0.50000000206214434417262282295268960297107696533203, 
   1.1754907046612932983601436560949782261786822346039*10^-8};
γ = M*ω/2;
norm = SetPrecision[0.00014216419373200363465950006063, 50];

intrp[r_, 
  re_] := (E^(-2 r (α + 
         r β)) (-E^(-((2 (me re^2 + 
                mp (r + re) (r + re + 2 me re)) γ)/M^2)) + 
      E^(-((2 γ (me (-mp r^2 + re^2 + mp re^2) + (1 + me) mp RealAbs[
                  r - re]^2))/M^2))) M^2)/(4 (1 + me) mp γ)

int[re_] := (2*π)/re norm^2*Integrate[r intrp[r, re], {r, 0, ∞}];

nint[re_?NumericQ, wp_ : MachinePrecision] := (2*π)/re norm^2*
   NIntegrate[r intrp[r, re], {r, 0, ∞}, WorkingPrecision -> wp];

int[10]

(* 4.975964881910113117485834958341383768420770382996*10^-7 *)

nint[10]

(* 4.97596*10^-7 *)

int[10] - nint[10]

(* 6.67038*10^-21 *)
```

Using arbitrary precision rather than MachinePrecision for `nint`

```
int[10] - nint[10, 49]

(* 0.*10^-55 *)
```

The form of `int2` requires extreme precision to obtain an accurate result.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

M = mp + me;

γ = M*ω/2;

intrp[r_, 
  re_] := (E^(-2 r (α + 
         r β)) (-E^(-((2 (me re^2 + 
                mp (r + re) (r + re + 2 me re)) γ)/M^2)) + 
      E^(-((2 γ (me (-mp r^2 + re^2 + mp re^2) + (1 + me) mp RealAbs[
                  r - re]^2))/M^2))) M^2)/(4 (1 + me) mp γ)

int2[re_] = (2*π)/re norm^2*
    Integrate[r intrp[r, re], {r, 0, ∞}] // Simplify;

Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 2000},
  int2[10] /. 
    Rationalize[{me -> 1, 
      mp -> 1, α -> 
       0.50000000206214434417262282295268960297107696533203, β -> 
       1.1754907046612932983601436560949782261786822346039*10^-8, 
      norm -> SetPrecision[0.00014216419373200363465950006063, 50], ω ->
        10^-4}, 0] // N[#, 250] &] // NumberForm[#, {55, 49}] &

(* N::meprec: Internal precision limit $MaxExtraPrecision = 2000.` reached while evaluating -(<<1>>/<<1>>). *)
```

[image]

**EDIT:** using your expression for `int2` provides the same results when using appropriate precision.

```
int2[re_] := (E^(-((2 (me + mp + 2 me mp) re^2 γ)/
          M^2)) M^2 norm^2 π^(3/
        2) (-E^(((2 α - (4 (1 + me) mp re γ)/
                 M^2)^2/(8 (β + (mp γ)/M^2)))) M^2 α + 
       E^((2 α + (4 (1 + me) mp re γ)/
               M^2)^2/(8 (β + (mp γ)/M^2))) M^2 α + 
       2 E^((2 α - (4 (1 + me) mp re γ)/
               M^2)^2/(8 (β + (mp γ)/M^2))) mp re γ + 
       2 E^((2 α + (4 (1 + me) mp re γ)/
               M^2)^2/(8 (β + (mp γ)/M^2))) mp re γ + 
       2 E^((2 α - (4 (1 + me) mp re γ)/
               M^2)^2/(8 (β + (mp γ)/M^2))) me mp re γ + 
       2 E^((2 α + (4 (1 + me) mp re γ)/
               M^2)^2/(8 (β + (mp γ)/M^2))) me mp re γ + 
       E^((2 α - (4 (1 + me) mp re γ)/
               M^2)^2/(8 (β + (mp γ)/
                M^2))) M^2 α Erf[(M^2 α - 
            2 (1 + me) mp re γ)/(Sqrt[
             2] M^2 Sqrt[β + (mp γ)/M^2])] - 
       2 E^((2 α - (4 (1 + me) mp re γ)/
               M^2)^2/(8 (β + (mp γ)/
                M^2))) mp re γ Erf[(M^2 α - 
            2 (1 + me) mp re γ)/(Sqrt[
             2] M^2 Sqrt[β + (mp γ)/M^2])] - 
       2 E^((2 α - (4 (1 + me) mp re γ)/
               M^2)^2/(8 (β + (mp γ)/
                M^2))) me mp re γ Erf[(M^2 α - 
            2 (1 + me) mp re γ)/(Sqrt[
             2] M^2 Sqrt[β + (mp γ)/M^2])] - 
       E^((2 α + (4 (1 + me) mp re γ)/
               M^2)^2/(8 (β + (mp γ)/
                M^2))) M^2 α Erf[(M^2 α + 
            2 (1 + me) mp re γ)/(Sqrt[
             2] M^2 Sqrt[β + (mp γ)/M^2])] - 
       2 E^((2 α + (4 (1 + me) mp re γ)/
               M^2)^2/(8 (β + (mp γ)/
                M^2))) mp re γ Erf[(M^2 α + 
            2 (1 + me) mp re γ)/(Sqrt[
             2] M^2 Sqrt[β + (mp γ)/M^2])] - 
       2 E^((2 α + (4 (1 + me) mp re γ)/
               M^2)^2/(8 (β + (mp γ)/
                M^2))) me mp re γ Erf[(M^2 α + 
            2 (1 + me) mp re γ)/(Sqrt[
             2] M^2 Sqrt[β + (mp γ)/M^2])]))/(8 Sqrt[
      2] (1 + me) mp re γ (M^2 β + 
       mp γ) Sqrt[β + (mp γ)/M^2]);

Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 2000}, 
  int2[10] /. γ -> M*ω/2 /. M -> mp + me /. 
    Rationalize[{me -> 1, 
      mp -> 1, α -> 
       0.50000000206214434417262282295268960297107696533203, β -> 
       1.1754907046612932983601436560949782261786822346039*10^-8, 
      norm -> SetPrecision[0.00014216419373200363465950006063, 50], ω ->
        10^-4}, 0] // N[#, 250] &] // NumberForm[#, {55, 49}] &

(* N::meprec: Internal precision limit $MaxExtraPrecision = 2000.` reached while evaluating <<1>>/<<1>>. *)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I said in the question that int[re] gives the right answer, but when I use the analytic form of its integration (namely int2[re]) it gives the wrong result. You have again used the integrating form for int2[re] which is not my desire one. Now when I replace int2[re] in your answer by the analytic form I get the wrong answer again!

Comment: Please use the analytic form (int2[re] in the question)for trying the solution.

Comment: Your form provides the correct result if appropriate precision is used. Presumably you got your form for `int2` by doing the symbolic integration which is exactly what I did for my `int2`

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to specify the desire precision at the first of the file? because I should specify the mp, me and omega and then the appropriate alpha, beta, norm and other constants are produced, so I can't specify their values for each calculation. Also I need to plot this function. How about plot I can produce the right answer?

Comment: Define all the constants with exact numbers when possible and high precision otherwise. To plot just use `nint` and include the working precision (second argument in my definition above) if needed.